# My eyes and my fingers are telling me different things

Tags: android, view, click, location

I programatically moved a layout with several child views. The child views all display in their new positions. However, the click and touch events are still working as if the views were in their old positions. What do I do?

**Edit:**

I used `translate` and `scale` to move the layout. Here is the code from a class extending LinearLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
    canvas.scale(-1, 1);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

I use this new layout in multiple activities, but the issue is the same for all of them. Here is one of the simpler layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.myapp.NewLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/chapter_gridview"
        style="@style/GridStyle" />

</com.example.myapp.NewLayout>
```

Any solutions?

**Update**

One way may be to update the LayoutParams but I am not sure how to do that yet. These are some related questions I found:

[OnClickListener issues after ImageButton moved after TranslateAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137657/onclicklistener-issues-after-imagebutton-moved-after-translateanimation)

[How can I dynamically set the position of view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android)

http://www.clingmarks.com/how-to-permanently-move-view-with-animation-effect-in-android/400

**Edit**

No solutions? I give up then.

Comment: Do you do this using Animation?

Comment: code and layouts please

Comment: plz use proper words in your question title

Comment: Answer for your question title is Consult a doctor

Comment: Haha. Very good. Very good. I need help, Dr. Vamshi. (Actually, I know that Mehul Joisar's comment above is correct. However, I've been coming at this problem from different angles for a long time now. I've posted questions before but they weren't getting any attention.)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are working with AnimationTranslation :** 
Your LinearLayout had been moved seemingly,but it's just visually moved.The LinearLayout is still where it is before the animation.

try this to your layout :

```
mylayout.layout(x,x,x,x);
```

I took my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860108/3014036)

you can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848562/translateanimation-not-working-as-expected)

***EDIT***

**If you are working with Canvas.translate :**

try padding in place of translate : `canvas.setPadding(getWidth(), 0);`

Comment: I read the links you gave several times but I can't see how to implement your advice. Maybe it is because I'm not using animation.

Comment: I tried `canvas.setPadding(getWidth(), 0);` but I got the error: The method setPadding(int, int) is undefined for the type Canvas